# Using maximum likelihood to derive regression coefficients in Python

Tags: python, math, statistics, sympy, mathematical-optimization

As a learning exercise for myself, I am trying to estimate the regression parameters using the MLE method in Python.

From what I have gathered, the log-likelihood function boils down to maximizing the following:

[image]

So I need to take partial derivatives with respect to the intercept and the slope, setting each to zero, and this should give me the coefficients.

I have been trying to approach this using sympy as follows:

```
from sympy import *
b = Symbol('b')# beta1
a = Symbol('a')# intercept
x = Symbol('x', integer=True)
y = Symbol('y', integer=True)
i = symbols('i', cls=Idx)

x_values = [2,3,2]
y_values = [1,2,3]
n = len(x_values)-1

function = summation((Indexed('y',i) - a+b*Indexed('x',i))**2, (i, 0, n))

partial_intercept = function.diff(a)

print(partial_intercept)
# 6*a - 2*b*x[0] - 2*b*x[1] - 2*b*x[2] - 2*y[0] - 2*y[1] - 2*y[2]

intercept_f = lambdify([x, y], partial_intercept)

inter = solve(intercept_f(x_values, y_values), a)

print(inter)
# [7*b/3 + 2]
```

I would have expected a single value for the slope, such that the 'b' variable is gone. However, I see that this wouldn't be possible given that the variable b is still there in my derivative equation.

Does anyone have any advice on where I am going wrong?

Thanks!

Edit : Fixed a typo in the codeblock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `7*b/2 + 2` at the end tell you that we have to satisfies `a = 7*b/2 + 2`, it depends on the quantity of `b`.

You should solve for both `a` and `b` as a system simultaneously.

In the following code, I find the relationship that `a` and `b` has to satisfies and solve them simultaneously.

```
from sympy import *

b = Symbol('b')# beta1
a = Symbol('a')# intercept
x = Symbol('x', integer=True)
y = Symbol('y', integer=True)
i = symbols('i', cls=Idx)

x_values = [2,3,2]
y_values = [1,2,3]
n = len(x_values)-1

function = summation((Indexed('y',i) - a+b*Indexed('x',i))**2, (i, 0, n))

partial_intercept = function.diff(a)

print(partial_intercept)
# 6*a - 2*b*x[0] - 2*b*x[1] - 2*b*x[2] - 2*y[0] - 2*y[1] - 2*y[2]

intercept_f = lambdify([x, y], partial_intercept)

inter = solve(intercept_f(x_values, y_values), a)

print(inter)
#[7*b/3 + 2]

partial_gradient = function.diff(b)

print(partial_gradient)
# 6*a - 2*b*x[0] - 2*b*x[1] - 2*b*x[2] - 2*y[0] - 2*y[1] - 2*y[2]

intercept_f = lambdify([x, y], partial_gradient)

inter2 = solve(intercept_f(x_values, y_values), b)
print(inter2)

ans = solve([a-inter[0], b-inter2[0]])
print(ans)
```

Here are the outputs:

```
6*a - 2*b*x[0] - 2*b*x[1] - 2*b*x[2] - 2*y[0] - 2*y[1] - 2*y[2]
[7*b/3 + 2]
2*(-a + b*x[0] + y[0])*x[0] + 2*(-a + b*x[1] + y[1])*x[1] + 2*(-a + b*x[2] + y[2])*x[2]
[7*a/17 - 14/17]
{a: 2, b: 0}
```

`a` should be set to be `2` and `b` should be set to be `0`.

Comment: But I have a question, what is this last part solve([a-inter[0], b-inter2[0]])? Is this setting up two equations, where the first is:
0 = a - 7*b/3 + 2
And the second:
0 = b - 7*a/17 - 14/17
?

Comment: Yes, I was setting up the linear equations.

Comment: Aaaaah, ok, so then the function solve() essentially splits the equations up into a matrix of coefficients and a matrix/vector of the variables (a, b) which lets me solve for a and b using something like gaussian elimination right?

Comment: could be gaussian elimination or some other matrix factorization trick, not sure how they work internally.

Comment: Ya ok. And one last clarification, its a - inter[0] because a = inter[0] and we bring 'a' onto the right hand side so we can set the equation to 0 = a - inter[0]?

Comment: sort of, I bring `inter[0]` to the left hand side and set it to `0`.

Comment: Ah yea my bad, I mixed up which one was the negative. But ok great that all makes sense, thanks a ton!